# using Regex get substring between underscore 2 and underscore 3 of string, vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a string like: Title Name_2021-04-13_A+B+C_Division.txt. I need to extract the A+B+C. The A+B+C may be other letters. I believe that using Regex would be the simplest way to do this. In other words I need to get the substring between underscore 2 and underscore 3 of string. All of my code is written in vb.net. I have tried:

`boatClass = Regex.Match(myFile, "(?<=_)(.*)(?=_)").ToString`

I know this is not right but I think it is close. What do I need to add or change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex code that will extract a substring between the second and third underscore of a string is:
`(?:[^_]+_){2}([^_]+)`
However, I chose to use the split function:
`myString.Split("_"c)(2)`